# First normal form

Tags: databases, normal-forms

I am confused about an aspect of the definition of first normal form in relational database model.

Codd 1970 ("A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks") defines normalization (implicitly to first normal form) as "eliminating nonsimple domains", where nonsimple domains are domains which have relations as elements.

Codd 1972 ("Further normalization of the database relational model.") has this definition: "A relation is in first normal form if it has the property that none of its domains has elements which are themselves sets." but also describes normalization as "eliminate domains which have relations as elements".

My question is: Isn't there a significant difference between domains with *relations* as elements and domains with *sets* as elements? It is not clear to me if Codd is broadening the definition or just using different language to say the same things.